# unicode emojis not showing on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, unicode, emoji, emojione

When I insert unicode emojis into a `<span>` using standard jQuery they don't appear with Chrome (v48), but do with Firefox (v43) and Safari (v9). Compare these screenshots:

**CHROME:**

[image: Chrome unicode emoji failure]

**FIREFOX:**

[image: Firefox unicode emoji success]

Any explanation here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the span had `font-weight:bold`. As soon as I put `font-weight:normal`, the emojis appeared.

Answer (score 2):

**[]** Additionally, if one has this issue and it's not related to the font-weight property, you may need to specify the 'charset' attribute in your head tag;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <span></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually because of the font weight.
Set the font-weight to 200px

Comment: Can you articulate your answer explaining the reason for that?

Comment: Yeah I'm curious as well, as this is really the reason it doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed the combination of all the answers above.

Without the `<meta charset utf-8" />`, the emoji shows gibberish.

With `font-weight: bold`, it shows nothing.

With `font-weight: 600` it shows bold.

Thanks a lot for asking and answering.