# Adjust CSS to make OSX Chrome Print Emoji

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, emoji

I cannot get Chrome on OSX to print emoji, is there any css trick or other?

Here are 2 emoji: 
When I try to print this page, the emoji space is preserved, but it's white. In Safari printing the emoji works just fine.

Here is a screenshot of the print preview of this page on Chrome:
[image: chrome print preview]

Comment: I see _three_ symbols: [`` is U+1f44d](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d "THUMBS UP SIGN"), [`` is U+1f1e6](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f1e6 "REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER A"), and [`` is U+1f1f9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f1f9 "REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER T").  Can you provide the character codes, an image of what you expect, and an image of what you get?  You should be able to take screen shots of the print preview. (I'm on Firefox on Linux.)

Comment: Ah, those are [regional indicator symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol), so `` indicates [Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria) by [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code) and the related emoji would (generally) be the Austrian flag.  I'm still not sure what you mean by "the emoji space" though.  Please provide your HTML/CSS code.

Comment: I mean the physical width and height on the paper.

Comment: Emojis are just font characters, so you can adjust their [`font-size`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) in CSS. You can even specify centimeters or inches.  I can't help you until you have sample code and a better demonstration of the issue so I can reproduce it.

Comment: The issue is that the emoji are not printed at all on chrome, but they are printed correctly on safari. Nothing to do with fontsize. More like a browser problem. The question is if there is a workaround for chrome.

Comment: I can't keep guessing at what you want.  This is a programming site.  You need to show us code.  If this is a font rendering issue, we might be able to help you with a workaround, but not without code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fabb/6aq7s3u9/

Comment: There is no code in your fiddle.  Why did mention (and tag) CSS if this is a direct font rendering issue?  I'm going to have to vote to close this as off-topic if this isn't a programming question.

Comment: As i said, i'm searching for a workaround (utilizing css) that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of dialog in the question's comments, it seems you have a font rendering issue (perhaps a Chrome bug).  I do not think this can be solved with any combination of HTML, CSS, or Javascript.

There is, however, the option to work around the issue by not using a font.

You can use a [vector image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_image_format) like [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) to have the same kind of scaling capabilities as a font:

- [SVG for THUMBS UP SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/thumbs_up_sign.svg) Unicode character
- [SVG for  REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f1e6/regional_indicator_symbol_letter_a.svg) Unicode character
- [SVG for  REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER T](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f1f9/regional_indicator_symbol_letter_t.svg) Unicode character
- [SVG for  [image]  Thumbs up sign](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Symbol_thumbs_up.svg)
- [SVG for  [image]  Austrian flag](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Flag_of_Austria.svg)

Just link to the SVG as an image and specify its dimensions either in HTML or in CSS as needed.

With a little work, you could automate conversion of user-generated emojis to images by using a dictionary of known images and supplement the misses with the either the SVG or the emoji PNG at FileFormat.Info.  They have a [list of emojis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/list.htm) you could scrape (assuming it's not a violation of [their terms of service](http://www.fileformat.info/about/tos.htm)) for PNGs as well as an SVG for every character (emoji or otherwise) which can be obtained from from just the character code.  For example, here's U+1f44d ():

```
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d
```

It'll be the only SVG link on the page, so you could do this in JS:

```js
var svg_src = fileformat_info.querySelector('a[href$=".svg"]').href;
```

That said, it'd be vastly preferable to have this ready-made rather than creating from scratch.  [@pandawan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36071212/519360) suggesting [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) looks promising.

Perhaps there *is* a CSS-only workaround: I've also read elsewhere that you can properly print these characters by [avoiding bold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35397633/519360) (and perhaps all font and text manipulation? perhaps just make the font size bigger?).  This may depend on the fonts installed on the client system.

Comment: Thanks for the persistence in answering the question, you've earned the bounty. Unfortunately the emoji are user-generated, so I would need to convert the emoji in an automated fashion. So I'm looking into twemoji described in the answer of @Pandawan

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a [rendering difference between Chrome and Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41347), I would not named it a bug since I do not believe that the expect behavior is defined anywhere (Firefox has issues rendering your emojis too by the way).

If you want a full and simple emoji support across all platforms you can use [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji), a small library developed by Twitter for this specific need.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What's strange is that Chrome shows the emoji just fine during browsing, but only does not show them when printing.

Comment: twemoji sounds interesting.